# Escaping white space in PDO odbc

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, whitespace

I have an access database I need to connect to, which has a table named [Received Projects] and in that table, we have fields named [Assigned To], [Assigned Date], and [Image Cnt].  MS Access and odbc in general would be okay with a select statement like:

```
SELECT [Received Projects].[Assigned To], [Received Projects].[Assigned Date], [Received Projects].[Image Cnt]
FROM [Received Projects]
WHERE ([Received Projects].[Image Cnt])>0)
```

However, I'm trying to connect with PDO in PHP, which does not like the square brackets.  It sort of likes something like this:

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT "Assigned To", "Assigned Date", "Image Cnt"
FROM "Received Projects"
WHERE ("Received Projects"."Image Cnt")>0)';
```

Except, it throws this error, indicating it doesn't know what the table is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "Received Projects" does not exist

I need to escape the white space in the table name, somehow.  Double quotes works on the column name, but not the table name.  I have tried single quotes, double quotes, backticks, and squarebrackets with variations of quotes.  Starting to wonder if it's not possible.

Comment: I have a kind of Resolution.  SHAZ's answer is accepted as correct.  Also, I was getting a bit fFrustrated and rewrote a block of code in pieces trying to determine the problem.  I may have had a syntax error somewhere or something.  SHAZ's help was very useful, because I at least knew that much is definitely right, and the specs don't seem very clear on the matter.  So, Many thanks!  I definitely couldn't have solved this without that assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below query. Its working fine ( TESTED )

```
$strSQL = 'SELECT `Assigned To`, `Assigned Date`, `Image Cnt` 
FROM `received projects` 
WHERE `received projects`.`Image Cnt` > 0';
```

Hope this fulfill your requirement. :)
NOTE: Please avoid white space. Better to use Camel naming convention.

Comment: I had tried backticks previously, and get this error:

[14-Nov-2014 01:44:45] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 2:     FROM `received projects`
                 ^' in C:\....\index.php:111

Comment: I do appreciate your effort.  I wonder why it works for you, but not on my machine.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer.  I appear to have some other kind of error in the code that was also not helping things.  Therefore you have provided a very useful answer.  Thank you!